# python scripts folder is empty

Tags: python, pip

[image][image: coustom install]

[image: pip folder is missing]

**pip was selected** while installing ,but when i checked scripts folder ,the folder was **empty**
since scripts are missing i cannot use pip cammand on terminal,new to programming please help me!!!

i tried installing pip this particular error showes up!!

Comment: check this path - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\

Comment: Check the above path by entering it to **This PC**'s url bar and if some scripts exist then you need to add environment variable for pip

Answer (score 5):

***FOR WINDOWS ONLY***

1. open cmd.
2. then type `pip help`, if pip is installed then a message would come explaining how to
   use it else an error message stating that the program is not found.
3. then type `python` and see whether that's installed properly , if you receive this
   `Python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch  file` then this means that python is not installed on your system and you need to
   reinstall it. Or if it is installed properly then you would get something like this

   ```
      Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit 
      (AMD64)] on win32
      Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
      >>>
   ```
4. to install pip download this [pip install](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and then open your cmd in that folder
   where you have installed it by using the `cd` command(like if you have installed it in downloads you should type in the cmd `cd Downloads`), then type this `python get-pip.py`.
5. And this should have installed pip on your system . (see step 1 to see if it works)
6. Then just upgrade pip and you are good to go , you can upgrade pip by `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
7. Then try installing a module like `pip install tksplash` in the cmd.

***FOR LINUX ONLY***

1. open your terminal and type `sudo apt install python3-pip`(works only on debian based disrtos like -: Ubuntu ,Kali , Parrot))

Comment: This is what i get "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: python was installed properly

Comment: yeah so just see step number 4 :)

Comment: maybe try this `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` and then do `python git-pip.py`

Comment: PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop> python git-pip.py
E:\Python3.9.5\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\git-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: oops sorry my bad its not `git` its `get` , im extremly srry for the troulble

Answer (score 1):

Your python scripts maybe installed in another path, like:

```
C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts
```

Remove `Python` folder in `Roaming` completely. Then uninetall and install python again.
Now check this path:

```
C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts
```

It's not empty.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have not install any pip packages.
2. you can install new one, then refresh dir.

```
pip install Flask
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing Anaconda will be better option. It has all packages required.
get-pip.py needs to be downloaded and run python get-pip.py.

Comment: i would not recommend anaconda to a begginer , it would confuse them with the venv and all

Answer (score 0):

pip not installed in scripts folder you feel tired again and again uninstall reinstall it but no solved here is trick and perfect answer simply install it via
customize in D or other drive not C drive i mean system or window drive not working
with python installation perfectly you will installed but pip commands not works
so 100% solution is install python in other not your main system drive all done smoothly

Answer (score 0):

1. using programs and features, search for and uninstall all of python, as well as the py launcher if its also installed.
2. Delete any C:/Python311 folder or any other location where python might be hiding.
3. Make sure that C:\Users*username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 is gone.
4. Download the python installer for 3.11
5. Run the installer as administrator. Do a custom install and make sure to check "add python to environment variables"
6. Restart all PowerShell command prompts and run python --version

My specific version is "Python 3.11.6".

Those are the steps that worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use Python 3.10, it installs `pip` properly out of the box.